# Load specific element on Woocommerce product category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, custom-taxonomy

is their a way via the functions.php or an other php method to don't load a specific div element on the shop / main page in woocommerce?

```
<div id="nm-shop" class="nm-shop nm-shop-sidebar-header images-lazyload images-show" style="min-height: 288px;">

    ...
</div>
```

This code includes a filter and the product archives of my shop page, but i only wanna display this at the category pages, where it already works, but not on the main page. How can i stop loading this div element on the shop / main page? I know that it's possible via css `display:none;` but that's not the cleanest solution.

I found the div class in the archive-product.php but i'm not sure if it's defined their to load it also on the shop page.

```
<div id="nm-shop" class="nm-shop <?php echo esc_attr( $shop_class ); ?>">
    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * NM: Removed - @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>

    <?php 
        // Shop header
        if ( $nm_theme_options['shop_header'] ) {
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product_nm_header' );
        }
    ?>

    <?php nm_print_shop_notices(); // Note: Don't remove (WooCommerce will output multiple messages otherwise) ?>

    <div id="nm-shop-products" class="nm-shop-products">
        <div class="nm-row">
            <?php 
                if ( $show_filters_sidebar ) {
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
                }
            ?>

            <div class="nm-shop-products-col <?php echo esc_attr( $shop_column_size ); ?>">
                <div id="nm-shop-products-overlay" class="nm-loader"></div>
                <div id="nm-shop-browse-wrap" class="nm-shop-description-<?php echo esc_attr( $nm_theme_options['shop_description_layout'] ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        // Results bar/button
                        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product_nm_results_bar' );
                    ?>

                    <?php
                        // Taxonomy description
                        if ( $show_taxonomy_description ) {
                            if ( $is_product_taxonomy ) {
                                /**
                                 * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
                                 *
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
                                 * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
                                 */
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
                            } else if ( strlen( $nm_theme_options['shop_default_description'] ) > 0 && ! isset( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ) { // Don't display on search
                                // Default description
                                nm_shop_description( $nm_theme_options['shop_default_description'] );
                            }
                        }
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {
                        /**
                         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
                         *
                         * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
                         * NM: Removed - @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                         * NM: Removed - @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                         */
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

                        // Set column sizes
                        global $woocommerce_loop;
                        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $nm_theme_options['shop_columns'];
                        $woocommerce_loop['columns_small'] = '2';
                        $woocommerce_loop['columns_medium'] = '3';

                        woocommerce_product_loop_start();

                        $nm_globals['is_categories_shortcode'] = false;

                        if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
                            while ( have_posts() ) {
                                the_post();

                                // Note: Don't place in another template (image lazy-loading is only used in the Shop and WooCommerce shortcodes can use the other product templates)                 
                                $nm_globals['shop_image_lazy_loading'] = ( $nm_theme_options['product_image_lazy_loading'] ) ? true : false;

                                /**
                                 * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                                 *
                                 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                                 */
                                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

                                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                            }
                        }

                        woocommerce_product_loop_end();

                        /**
                         * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
                         *
                         * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                         */
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
                    } else {
                        /**
                         * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
                         *
                         * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
                         */
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        // Sidebar/filters popup
        if ( $show_filters_popup ) {
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product_nm_filters_popup' );
        }
    ?>

</div>

<?php
    /**
     * Hook: nm_after_shop.
     */
    do_action( 'nm_after_shop' );

    get_footer( 'shop' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [woocommerce conditional tag `is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) to target product category archives pages only, this way:

```
<?php if( is_product_category() ) : ?>
<div id="nm-shop" class="nm-shop nm-shop-sidebar-header images-lazyload images-show" style="min-height: 288px;">
    ...
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It should works

Comment: thx for the feedback is this coming in the function.php? I'm using a theme wich i try to modify.

i found the code of it in the archive-product.php. I updated my post with the code. Maybe there is a hook wich defines that's it's should load it on the shop page. Couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Just create a separate file `.php` with your like below

```
<div id="nm-shop" class="nm-shop nm-shop-sidebar-header images-lazyload images-show" style="min-height: 288px;">
...
</div>
```

And then you can include it where you want it in your pages, just by doing:

```
include 'name_of_your_file.php';
```

If you have any questions, docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php